# Excel copy range to array clicking into checkbox

Tags: excel, vba

### i have a CheckBox and click on the event something like this:

```
If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
Range("H5:H38").Value = Range("H4").Value
```

---

so that the column values ​​h5 until H38 become identical to the value in cell h4.

---

```
If CheckBox1.Value = False Then
```

---

Now do I need to know how the values ​​H5: H38 in an array so that when the User uncheck the checkbox, return values ​​to be the same before the event.
That is, before transforming values ​​h5: H38 in the value contained in h4 need to save the values ​​in an array to be able to undo the action if the User uncheck the checkbox. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that will convert any range to an array:

```
Public Function CreateArrayFromRange(yourRange As Range)
Dim retVal() As Variant, xCell As Range, upperIndex As Integer, tic As Integer

    If yourRange.Cells.Count > 0 Then
        upperIndex = yourRange.Cells.Count - 1
        ReDim retVal(0 To upperIndex)
        tic = -1
        For Each xCell In yourRange
            tic = tic + 1
            retVal(tic) = xCell.Value
        Next xCell
        CreateArrayFromRange = retVal
    Else
        CreateArrayFromRange = Array("ERROR")
    End If

End Function
```

The implementation of this would look something like this.

```
Dim myArray()
myArray = CreateArrayFromRange(Range("H5:H38"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an excert to do what you requested. Because you said you need to know how, I added a few comments prior to a few lines to make it completely clear how this works.

```
Option Explicit
'Declare a private variant to store the range formulas
'Variable is declared as private so that it remains in scope within the module
'Variable could also be declared as static within the sub with the same results.
Private rangeFormulas As Variant
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
    'Transfer the range formulas to the variant.
    rangeFormulas = Range("H5:H38").Formula
    Range("H5:H38").Value = Range("H4").Value
Else
    'Restore the formulas from the private variant variable.
    Range("H5:H38").Formula = rangeFormulas 
End If
End Sub
```

Technically, I could have used `rangeFormulas = Range("H5:H38").Value`and `Range("H5:H38").Value = rangeFormulas`, but I thought it would be better if you restored the formulas instead which has the same visible result.